# Retrieve images from sqlite3 database for Face Verification

Tags: python

```
    import sqlite3
    from deepface import DeepFace
    from PIL import Image
    from io import BytesIO

def connect_to_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('user_photo.db')
    return conn


def get_file_from_db(customer_id):
    cursor = connect_to_db().cursor()
    select_fname = """SELECT photo from photos where customer_id = ?"""
    cursor.execute(select_fname, (customer_id,))
    item = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.connection.commit()
    return item

def get_testsign(customer_id):
    cursor = connect_to_db().cursor()
    select_sign = """SELECT testphoto from test where customer_id = ?"""
    cursor.execute(select_sign, (customer_id,))
    item = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.connection.commit()
    return item

def matchNew():
   try:
       input_image = get_testsign(customer_id)
       input_image_open = [Image.open(BytesIO(x)) for x in input_image]
       reg_image = get_file_from_db(customer_id)
       reg_image_open = [Image.open(BytesIO(x)) for x in reg_image]
       obj = DeepFace.verify(input_image_open, reg_image_open)
       print(obj)
       return print({"error":False})
   except Exception as e:
        print(e)
   return print({"error": True})

if __name__=='__main__':
    customer_id = '080abc'
    matchNew()
```

The above code is to get images from the database and verify for face verification. The images are stored in the database as BLOB. DeepFace.verify takes two arguments i.e. two pictures for face verification. The error I am getting is **('Invalid arguments passed to verify function: ', <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=267x188 at 0x2033A8B9340>)
{'error': True}**

I am using python 3.8 on windows 10.

This is how the tables inside the database look:
[Table photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj8bj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The both input_image_open and reg_image_open are PIL images. DeepFace expects exact image path, base64 encoded image or numpy array as input. You can convert pil images to numpy as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
input_image_open_np = np.array(input_image_open.convert("L"))
reg_image_open_np = np.array(reg_image_open.convert("L"))
obj = DeepFace.verify(input_image_open_np, reg_image_open_np)
```